# Service и обновление информации в закрытой Activity

Tags: android

Пример:

1) Есть сервис, который обрабатывает определенным образом получаемые JSON - данные и дополняет результатом некий список (например просто String).

2) Есть Activity, которая может быть закрыта. В ней текстовое поле, которое при открытии этой activity должно содержать актуальное содержимое String, а также обновляться в реальном времени.

Как можно это реализовать?

(p.s. Верно ли я решил со String? Не знал, где еще хранить информацию пока активность закрыта.)

Comment: sharedpreferences, sqlite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо хранить актуальную информацию в месте которое "живет" пока живет приложение. Вариантов много, может быть переменная (которая точно не умрет), может быть база данных, может быть в Sharedpreferences (но это извращение как по мне) и т.д.. Получается когда заходит новая информация вы постоянно сетите в это место актуальную инфо, а при запуске Активити идете за инфой в это место. 
В активити которая сетит данные переопределяете метод onStart:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getData; //<-- Это ваш метод который необходимо создать
            //в нутри которо Вы идете за актуальными данными и сетит их в view
}
```

UPD:
Почитайте про [Android Architecture](https://habrahabr.ru/post/332562/) или можно использовать EventBus. Как вариант можно использовать подход на RxJava:

создаете интерфейс для ваших ивентов (разные события, в Вашем случаем получение новых данных)

```
public interface Event<T> {


void send(T object);

Observable<T> toObservable();

boolean hasObservers();

void complete();

}
```

Далее создаете класс

```
public class IncomeDataEvent implements Event<Data> { //Data <-- это ваш объект с данными, может быть просто String если надо

private static final BehaviorSubject<Data> mSendMessageEvent = BehaviorSubject.create(); // можно использовать PublishSubject (разницу сами посмотрите), но в Вашем случае нужен BehaviorSubject

@Override
public void send(Data data) {
    mSendMessageEvent.onNext(data);
}

@Override
public Observable<Data> toObservable() {
    return mSendMessageEvent;
}

@Override
public boolean hasObservers() {
    return mSendMessageEvent.hasObservers();
}

@Override
public void complete() {
    mSendMessageEvent.onComplete();
}
}
```

Далее в Активити подписываетесь/отписываетесь на ивенты

```
//В полях класса объявляете переменные
private CompositeDisposable mCompositeDisposable;
private IncomeDataEvent mIncomeEvent = new IncomeDataEvent();


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mCompositeDisposable == null || mCompositeDisposable.isDisposed()) {
        mCompositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    }
//Подписываетесь на получение новых данных  
mCompositeDisposable.add(syncManager.getEditTripEvent()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(incomeData -> { //incomeData - это последние входящие данные
            texView.setText(incomeData); //Тут вы сетите входящие данные в вашу view
        }));

    @Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
  mCompositeDisposable.dispose();//отписываетесь от обновленией (необходимо делать что бы небыли утечки памяти)
}
```

Осталось реализовать отсылку данных. Для этого в вашем сервисе создайте экземпляр класса IncomeDataEvent и отправляйте данные таким образом:

```
mIncomeEvent.send(data);
```

Comment: Иду при запуске, а как ее обновлять на экране? Или сделать там отдельный цикл с паузами? Просто если бы она всегда была открыта - я бы обошелся одним циклом с паузами в сервисе.

Comment: Насколько понимаю, я могу отправлять данные в активность через Intent? Сейчас попробую.

Comment: У активити есть жизненный цикл - вы что-то знаете про это? Если нет, то обязательно прочитайте. Так вот, в этом жизненном цикле есть метод onStart  - который отрабатывает всегда когда запускается активити. Вот в этом методе и идете за данными. Обновлю ответ.

Comment: Простите, если плохо выразил мысль, но это же обновит данные всего один раз, при старте активити? Или я ошибаюсь? Мне нужно, чтобы в реальном времени содержимое TextView на экране менялось. Пока что вижу выход в статической переменной и еще одном while(true) в открываемой активити.

Comment: Да, я не правильно Вас понял, обновил ответ

Comment: Можно еще у вас спросить? Вижу что эти методы несут больше кода, чем мой Thread.sleep() в бесконечном цикле. Мой способ сильно хуже? И вообще, возможно я неправильно делаю? Я JSON данные получаю таким же образом (в беск. цикле и с паузой). Думал потом их записывать в статическую переменную, а при открытии активити - еще одним циклом с паузой их читать. В чем минусы такого способа?

Comment: Так, читаю https://habrahabr.ru/post/124484/, вижу что я неправильно делаю со вторым циклом - блокирую UI поток. Буду разбираться.

Comment: Sleep - это костыли, AsyncTask - устарел, т.к. есть много нюансов с "утечкой памяти". Вообще google предлогает Android Architecture Components - рекомендую изучить его. Этот подход от гугла, относительно не сложный в реализации и понимании.